# RHEL doesn't complete boot after kernel update

Tags: linux, boot

I have a somewhat strange problem.  I run SL6.5 (a RHEL clone) and a couple months ago updated the kernel.  The kernel release notes can be found [here](http://ftp1.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6x/x86_64/updates/security/repoview/kernel.html).  I updated to the 431.17.1 kernel.  During boot, the boot process mostly completes, but it hangs right before the login screen appears.  If I boot to the older kernel (431.11.2), everything boots fine.  The 431.20.3 kernel acts just like the 431.17.1.  Below is the screen when it hangs (I apologize for the quality/glare, there is no good way to take a screen cap during boot).

[image]

Note that sshd has sucessfully started at this point, so I booted into a liveCD onto one of my co-workers desktops and used ssh to connect to the computer.  The connect worked fine, I was able to navigate my root file system, and even started matlab using X11 forwarding which appeared without issue.

I have tried looking at the /var/log and don't see any major errors occuring during boots.  I am wondering what I can do to sort out what is causing this, and how I might fix it.

Comment: Looks like it hangs at "atd" do you know what that is./

Comment: no, but I turned it off in ntsysv, and it just stopped right after the crond.

Comment: You need to determine what it is or figure a way to skip `atd` and `crond`

Comment: I turned off the last 4 services on the list one by one and it had no effect.  And is the last service to start before the login screen appears.  I think it is hanging somewhere in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to figure out what was hanging by using `ntsysv` to turn off services shown in the image in the question and getting nowhere, I decided to see if it was the actual display of the login screen that caused the problem.  I checked, and NVIDIA had released a new driver, so I downloaded it an booted into run-level 3 to install it.  At this point I realized that the new kernel booted fine in run-level 3.

After installing the new driver, the new kernel booted without issue.  I don't know if the new driver solved it, or if rebuilding the old driver would have been sufficient (I am guessing that it would have been).